# Second y axis and vertical line

Tags: python, seaborn, axes, violin-plot

I am creating a violinplot using the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.violinplot(data=df[['SoundProduction','SoundForecast','diff']])
ax.set_ylabel("Sound power level [dB(A)]")
```

It gives me the folowing result:

[image: violinplot]

Is there any way I can plot `diff` on a second y-axis so that all three series become clearly visible?

Also, is there a way to plot a vertical line in between 2 series? In this case I want a vertical line between `SoundForecast` and `diff` once they are plotted on two different axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using multiple subplots, which are easily set up using the [plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) (see lots more [subplot examples](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-subplot)).

This allows you to display your distributions on scales that are appropriate, and don't "waste" the display space. Most(all?) of seaborn's plotting functions accept the `ax=` argument so you can set the axes where the plot will be rendered.  The axes also have clear separations between them.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# generate some random distribution data
n = 800 # samples
prod = 95 + 5 * np.random.beta(0.6, 0.5, size=n); # a bimodal distribution
forecast = prod + 3*np.random.randn(n) # forecast is noisy estimate around the "true" production
diff = prod-forecast  # should be with mu 0 sigma 3
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([prod, forecast, diff]).T, columns=['SoundProduction','SoundForecast','diff']); 

# set up two subplots, with one wider than the other
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, num=1,  gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[2,1]})

# plot violin distribution estimates separately so the y-scaling makes sense in each group
sns.violinplot(data=df[['SoundProduction','SoundForecast']], ax=ax[0])
sns.violinplot(data=df[['diff']], ax=ax[1])
```

[image]